# Can i Use Axios on a non SPA project?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am feed up with ajax long style of sending request, I have used axios on an SPA project and its pretty cool, I checked on thee documentation to see how it works and works great, however if I try to make a request it tows an error of unauthenticated, i am using Laravel php framework as my code back-end, if I try to run this directly on ajax, it works, or on a normal form it works also.

Plus i don't have any authentication middle setup anywhere.

Here is a documentation to the library [Axios Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Here is my Sample code

```
axios.get('/home', {} , {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN'    : "{{csrf_token()}}",
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        })
            .then(function(ressponse){
                console.log(success);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error)
            })
 });
```

I a only returning all the request in my controller and not special

So my Question is, is it a problem with axios, or laravel, or i can not just use axios without any SPA framework (e.g react, vue etc.).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's unauthenticated because you aren't setting `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the headers.

You are setting a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` property on the config object, but that is meaningless.

```
axios.get('/home', {} , {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN'    : "{{csrf_token()}}",
                // X-Requested-With is an ugly hack and you should use an Accept header instead of this (not as well as!)
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                // You're making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content-type of.
                // 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        })
```

Comment: Better yet, do what Laravel's `bootstrap.js` does and set it by default on *all* Axios requests, by setting `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']` and `window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN']`. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4202ec978dccc1ff0a193b85b2f362055cbd85be/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L36

Answer (score 1):

**if your axios config is in js file then you have to do below steps**

1- you have to put this meta in your page layout header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

2- and change

```
'X-CSRF-TOKEN'    : "{{csrf_token()}}",
```

to

```
'X-CSRF-TOKEN'    :document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
```

in your js file

and test it, if it works then your problem was because of js file is not a blade file so {{csrf_token()}} in your axios config will not rendered by laravel to csrf token